# Convert list of list to dict, list for repeating values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is my code:

```
l = [['A',11],['A',12],['B',13],['B',14],['C',15],['C',16],]
d = {}

>>> for a in l:
...     if a[0] in d:
...         s = d[a[0]]
...         s.append(a[1])
...         d[a[0]] = s
...     else:
...         d[a[0]] = [a[1]]
...
```

I get my dictionary as expected.

```
print (d)
{'A': [11, 12], 'B': [13, 14], 'C': [15, 16]}
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Key is to create a list of second element in the list of list, if the key repeats.

Comment: use a `collections.defaultdict`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in l:
   d[k].append(v)
```

Comment: Really? Why to you need an external library?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Where's the **external** library?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ to avoid creating a list-object on every iteration.

Comment: I mean, why do you need to _import_ something?

Comment: hey guys why answering a triplicate?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm out of dupe hammer votes :p

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You create one anyway?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you deleted your answer anyway.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, after you marked it...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ way to go. Respect, man (one day I'll teach you how to be the king of the dupehammer. Wait, I'm not the one with 0 close votes :))

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ not, with a `defaultdict` you *only* create one when needed. Using `.setdefault(x, [])` creates an empty dictionary, then passes it to `setdefault` on every iteration, even when you don't need it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, that was informative. I still think not importing a package if you don't need it is a good, viable alternative, but I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `itertools` isn't `pandas`. You can import it in a flash. and it comes in the standard distrib.